# Getting new unique number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server database that looks like this:

Table structure:

[image]

Sample data:

[image]

I want to get **next unique code** from the table.

The answer that should come next is **5** as last code is **3** and next code should be **4** but **4 already exists** so again by adding 1 the answer should be **5**. How to do this? can anyone help me with a piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join, like below.

This SQL is getting the code of the first row which doesn't have a successor, and adding one to it.

The subquery in the `from` clause is adding a fake code of `0`, for the case when the next available code is 1 (if there was no `(1, 1)` in the `@table`, for example).

```
declare @table table (id int, code int) 
insert @table values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 45), (5, 5)

select top 1 t1.code + 1
from (select null as id, 0 as code union all select * from @table) t1
left join @table t2 on t2.code = t1.code + 1
where t2.code is null
order by t1.code
```